# How to get json object by javascript item

Tags: javascript, json

So I have an array of json objects like these below. Which are retrieved using XMLHTTP. Now I want to 'select' value where name == "test" using javascript how do I do this? I know I can do for example data[0] but that is not how I want is because the Id can change.

```
[

{"name" : "test", "value": "Something"},
{"name" : "test2", "value": "Something else"}

]
```

Comment: loop over each element in your response, and test for the one you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use loops for this, so you can use `Array.filter` and you can get the first match, ex.:

```js
var items = [{"name" : "test", "value": "Something"},{"name" : "test2", "value": "Something else"}];

var where = "name", is = "test2"
, select = items.filter(function(item){ return item[where] == is})[0];

console.log(select)
```

Comment: If it’s only one expected result, you could use `find` instead of `filter`. If there can be multiple results, the `[0]` at the end should be deleted.

Comment: `find` is only supports on ES6

Answer (score 0):

You are already using JSON Objects, but you have nested them into an array, which have a number as index, don't mistake the index for the ID, because the ID should represent uniqueness therefore must be immutable - you can, for example sort your array.

Now, your question says that you are looking for a specic information, i.e. the name, well, it will depend on how you want to do things though all ways I can think will have some sort of loop through the array and each interaction will check if the object matchs your conditions or not - normally this filter operation is delegated to a function.

Answer (score 0):

i find the `lodash` library insanely useful for data manip like this. you can do:

```
var item = _.find(data, {'name' : 'test' })
```

complete example:

```
var _ = require('lodash')
var data = [
  {"name" : "test", "value": "Something"},
  {"name" : "test2", "value": "Something else"} ]
var item = _.find(data, {'name' : 'test' })
console.log(item)
// => { name: 'test', value: 'Something' }
```

More info: https://lodash.com/docs#find

**Edit:** use `JSON.parse(my_json)` to first convert JSON into a bona fide JavaScript data structure, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = [........];

function findInJson(json, key, val) {
    for (var i in json) {
        if (json[i][key] == val)
            return json[i];
    }
    return false;
}

console.log( findInJson(json, 'name', 'test') );
```

will return you object from the array if found, otherwise - false